# Finding EyeTV Activation Key from existing install?

Tags: macos

I have EyeTV Lite installed on my old computer.

I'd like to move it over to a new computer. I simply copied over the application bundle and everything under `/Library/Application Support/EyeTV`, but when I try to start up the application on the new computer, it launches the EyeTV Startup Assistant and asks me for the Activation Key.

I bought the EyeTV 8 years ago... I've long since lost the box, disk, manual, etc... all I have is the software installed on the one computer and the USB dongle.

If I launch the EyeTV Startup Assistant on my old computer, it shows me this for my Activation Key:

```
ARYGC-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX
```

How could I figure out what the rest of the Activation Key is, or otherwise transfer it to my new computer? I've looked through Keychain Access... there's nothing mentioning `Elgato` (name of the company that wrote the software) or `EyeTV`...

There appears to be a SQLite database at `/Library/Application Support/EyeTV/EyeTVEPG.db`, but when I try opening it with Datum (app I found on the app store), it says the database file is password protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I copied over these three files that I found inside of `/Library/Preferences`:

```
com.elgato.eyetv.devices.plist
com.elgato.eyetv.plist
com.elgato.eyetv.world.plist
```

Not sure which one of them was the important one, but once I copied those three files over, Setup Assistant stopped asking for my Activation Key, and the application launched properly. Hope this helps someone else in the future, and if not (the product might be too obscure - it's kind of hard to find anything about it online at all, given it was discontinued several years ago), at least it'll help me should I ever want to copy the application to another computer again.

Answer (score 1):

The above didn't work for me.

I followed this link instead: https://www.geniatech.eu/eyetv/faq/how-do-i-recover-my-lost-eyetv-activation-key/

I then downloaded the "EyeTV Reporter" application which enabled me to make a full backup and re-installation my copy of EyeTV on my new Mac (without being prompted for any serials).